# Tomcat 7 LifeCycleListener

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

I have been searching for days on how to get this to work but I have had no success.

I have a project which listens on port 6789 and when a connection is made I need to perform some specific actions. To do that I am trying to use a [listener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html) so that anytime that my servers `Engine`is run upon a connection being made.

Basically a mobile application is going to connect to an instance of a server, as soon as the connection is made, the server needs to authenticate the user, then receive data from the phone and place it in the database. If there is another way to do this please let me know. I have looked at filters but those need a url path to activate, and I also do not know how to use a servlet which will fire when a connection is made!

I have this so far in my server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="6789" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
        <Listener className="Listeners.EngineListener" />

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                resourceName="UserDatabase" />
        </Realm>

        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
            unpackWARs="true">

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log."
                suffix=".txt" />

            <Context docBase="PhoneListener" path="/PhoneListener"
                reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PhoneListener">
            </Context>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

I have the full path to the file in the `<Listener>` tag. This is the same way I have executed many filters (authentication and noCache).

The class which implements the `LifeCycleListener` is here"

```
package Listeners;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EngineListener implements LifecycleListener 
{

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("The engine listener is working!");
    }

}
```

The bean declaration is meaningless here, I get the same result with and without the bean declaration.

I have been working at this for a few days now.

I have installed maven and used it to fix dependencies. I have made new projects in new workspaces in an attempt to remedy and class path errors. I have tried to switch from the Majorra JSF library to the MyFaces library, I get the same errors. I am honestly at my wits end with the Listener.

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors? I don't see the actual problem you're experiencing

Comment: wow I forgot to put that, I am getting a class not found exception on the Listeners.PhoneListener class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there were no errors in my code, but an error with where files are placed. I have exported the `PhoneListener`project as a `.jar` and put it into the /lib folder of the server I am awaiting a connection on.

The server could not find my `Listeners.PhoneListener` as it was not in the start up directory of the server itself.